# Scroll to specific item using JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div which looks like below. When a user clicks on alphabets from left, the right side should scroll to that alphabet heading.

[image: Div]

```
<div class="left">
    <ul class="letters">
        <li>
            <a href="#letter-A">A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#letter-B">B</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="right brands-scroll" style="max-height: 320px;overflow-y: scroll;">
    <ul>
        <li><h3 id="letter-A">A</h3></li>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Alphanso</li>
        <li><h3 id="letter-B">B</h3></li>
        <li>Ball</li>
        <li>Banana</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery code

```
$('ul.letters li a').on('click', function (t) {
    t.preventDefault();
    var targetSec = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.brands-scroll').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + targetSec).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

I tried this solution, but it didn't work properly
[jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Comment: Have you seen this https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ ?

Comment: It would be great if you provide jquery code that you tried.

Comment: @Developer107 Jquery code added

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` will give you '#letter-A' for instance which is then added with selector again as `$('#'+'#letter-A')` Please remove the extra #

Comment: It worked, but the scroll is random not the desired

Comment: I reduced the `max-height` for brands-scroll and got it to work properly - `max-height: 106px;`

Comment: check here - https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/jLn9h969/

Comment: @Developer107 the fiddle you provided is wrong. Click on `A` twice. It will break.

Comment: @RinoRaj ahh my bad! I didn't see that coming. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".letters li a").click(function() {
  var container = $('.right'),id = $(this).attr('href'),
    scrollTo = $(id);

  container.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
  });
});
```

Click on any of the alphabet in the demo and you can see the result.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xY7tx/2370/)**